# Can anyone please explain this "dead code" example?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, if-statement, dead-code

Some explaination about the following snippets:
I'm messing with some Bluetooth discovery calls. For that I'm using a callback, which will be invoked if a `BluetoothDevice` is found or not. If no device was found the parameter is null:

```
@Override
public void provideDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
    super.provideDevice(device);
    Log.v("MainActivity","device name = " +device.getName());
    if(device != null) {

        mBinder.start(device);

    } else { 

        Toast.makeText(this, "No Device found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

**Eclipse is telling me that the else block is dead code.**

If I move the `Log` call in the if-block the warning is gone:

```
@Override
public void provideDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
    super.provideDevice(device);

    if(device != null) {

        Log.v("MainActivity","device name = " +device.getName());
        mBinder.start(bc);

    } else { 

        Toast.makeText(this, "No Device found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

I know that the first snippet will throw a NPE if the parameter is null. That's not the problem in this example.

**I would like to know why the `dead code warning` appears.**

I can provide the full code, if this isn't enough to tell me what's going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You dereference `device` in the log statement.

If you get past that line of code, `device` *cannot* be null, because you'd get an NPE if it was.

This means the `else` statement is redundant, because if the code gets that far, it can't be `null`.

Comment: From where should the compiler know that the parameter is null and I made a mistake in my code by risking a NPE? Is the compiler really thinking "The programer knows what he is doing"?

Comment: @SteveBenett The compiler is saying "it's been dereferenced; it can no longer be null in this code path"--because the only way to get that far is to *not* have an NPE. It's not so much that it's assuming we know what we're doing, rather that it will only make assumptions it *knows* it can make (and it won't make *all* assumptions it *could* make, either).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that, in the first example, Java knows that it is impossible for `device != null` to be false, since if it were null, you would have gotten an NPE from the log statement,  and would not reach that code.